# Another JSON Parsing

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, unrecognized-selector

I'm new in XCode and Objective-C and try to learn it. 
I have tried to search on the net about this problem and can't find the solution that works for me. Maybe because I'm using a bad keyword to search. Can you help me for below problems? It seems that this is a very novice problem. I'm banging my head at the wall right now....

I have a JSON response:

```
{"message":"success","personal":{"userID":"111","companyID":"11","nameUser":"User Name Here","fotoURL":"http:\/\/myurl.com\/data\/photo\/11\/111.jpg"}}
```

I have succeed to contain userID, companyID and nameUser into variables in AppDelegate variables. (I'm going to use this variables in multiple view controllers).

Currently I'm using this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
myAppDelegate.userID = [jsonData [@"personal"][@"userID"] intValue];
myAppDelegate.companyID = [jsonData [@"personal"][@"companyID"] intValue];
myAppDelegate.fotoURL = [jsonData [@"personal"][@"fotoURL"] stringValue];
```

The error message is: -[__NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e89ae0

But I'm failing to contain fotoURL. Would you mind to show where I do wrong? And is this a best practice?

I have browsed to search how to parse JSON and find many methods, such as using [nsdictionary_object objectForKey:@"json-node"] etc. But none are succeeded.

Thank you before

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It is *very* simple to parse JSON in Objective-C if you understand the syntax; very hard if you just try to modify examples.

Comment: And you didn't search the web very hard if you didn't find info about the "unrecognized selector" error message.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I know that my JSON response is in a good syntax so I didn't search it in json.org. Of course I search "unrecognized selector" in the first place...but it seems that I didn't understand the solutions or any references about it. Now I know I need to search "xcode online courses" in the web. :)

Comment: Do you know how to read the Cocoa specs?

Comment: Not yet, sir. But I'm learning right now...

Comment: [Bookmark](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fotoURL is already a string, so you don't need to call stringValue on it.

You can tell this by [**__NSCFString** stringValue], the __NSCFString means the object is of class __NSCFString (which is effectively an NSString).

Comment: when I remove "stringValue", it will show the error message: "expected identifier"

Comment: you probably haven't removed the extraneous square brackets.

Comment: Ah! great! Thank you very much Jonathan. I know that this is a silly question. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I'm surprised there is no `-stringValue` method on NSString.  You could add a trivial one (that just returns `self`) to the NSString class via a Category.

Comment: @Flortify - And there should be an `intValue` method on `int`?  It's bad enough that folks use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString]` all the time.

Comment: @HotLicks: (1) `int` is a primitive type, not a class, therefore, there could never be an `-intValue` method on it, and (2) perhaps you meant `NSNumber` … which **does** have an `intValue` method.  See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsnumber_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumber/intValue.

Comment: @HotLicks: there is also a **really good security reason** to use the `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString]` idiom (or the corresponding `printf()` equivalent): it can prevent format-string attacks (like SQL-injection attacks), which the simpler `[NSString stringWithFormat:someString, x, y, z]` is vulnerable to, whenever `someString` could have come from an outside source.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string.

Comment: @Floritfy, `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someString]` is useless, you're not using it create a formatted string, which `[NSString stringWithFormat:someString, x, y, z]` is. (though as you say, if someString can come form an outside source, both are vulnerable)

Comment: @Flortify - As you have so aptly illustrated, using that idiom is always a sign that the user doesn't know what he's doing.